# Wrong eigenvector with MKL sgeev

Tags: fortran, lapack

I want to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix. I'm using `sgeev` of MKL lapack.

I have this very simple test code:

```
integer :: i,n, info
real, allocatable:: A(:,:), B(:,:), C(:,:)
real, allocatable:: wr(:), wi(:), vl(:, :), vr(:, :), work(:)
n=3
allocate(vr(n,n), vl(n,n), wr(n), wi(n), work(4*n))
allocate(A(n,n),B(n,n), C(n,n))
A(1,:)=(/-1.0,3.0,-1.0/)
A(2,:)=(/-3.0,5.0,-1.0/)
A(3,:)=(/-3.0,3.0,1.0/)
call sgeev('V','V',n,A,n,wr,wi,vl,n,vr,n,work,size(work,1),info)
print*,info
do i=1,n
  print*,i,wr(i),wi(i)
enddo
print*,'vr'
do i=1, n
  print*, vr(i,:)
enddo
print*,'vl'
do i=1, n
  print*, vl(i,:)
enddo
```

It gives the right eigenvalues (`2, 2, 1`) but the wrong eigenvectors.

I have:

```
 vr
 -0.577350259      0.557844639     -0.539340019    
 -0.577350557      0.704232574     -0.273908198    
 -0.577349961      0.439164847      0.796295524    
 vl
 -0.688247085     -0.617912114     -0.815013587    
  0.688247383      0.771166325      0.364909053    
 -0.229415640     -0.153254643      0.450104564
```

when vr should be

```
-1   1   1
 0   1   1
 3   0   1
```

What am I doing the wrong way?

Comment: What is `A_sparse%nl` ? Please show a *complete* code we can compile and test ourselves.

Comment: The matrix `{{-1,3,-1},{-3,5,-1},{-3,3,1}}` does not have the eigenvalues `{1,2,3}`. See e.g. [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=eigenvectors+%7B%7B-1%2C3%2C-1%7D%2C%7B-3%2C5%2C-1%7D%2C%7B-3%2C3%2C1%7D%7D).

Comment: Also could you edit the question to tell us how you got the "correct" evecs, and how you know the ones you are getting are wrong? Evecs are tricksy things to test ... Have you checked AQ-QE is approximate zero, where Q are the evecs, and is a diagonal matrix with the evals on the diag?

Comment: sorry for the mistakes I edited my code. About the eigen vectors I checked on several online app and it's also the example of this wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your matrix is [degenerate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) (has two eigenvalues which are the same as one another), so the corresponding eigenvectors can be an arbitrary linear combination of the two degenerate eigenvectors.

Also, the output of `sgeev` [normalises the eigenvectors](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d3/dfb/group__real_g_eeigen_ga104525b749278774f7b7f57195aa6798.html), whereas the eigenvectors you have given are not normalised.

The first eigenvalue given is `1`, and the corresponding eigenvector is the first column of `vr`, `l1=(-0.57..., -0.57..., -0.57...)`. This is proportional to the third eigenvector you have given, `(1, 1, 1)`.

The second and third eigenvalues are both `2`. The corresponding eigenvectors are the second and third columns of `vr`, `l2=(0.55..., 0.70..., 0.43...)` and `l3=(-0.53..., -0.27..., 0.79...)`. Taking `0.27...*l2+0.70...*l3` gives `(-0.22..., 0, 0.66...)`, proportional to `(-1, 0, 3)`, and taking `0.79...*l2-0.43...*l3` gives `(0.66..., 0.66..., 0)`, proportional to `(1, 1, 0)`.

Comment: oh I completely forgot this fact about degenerate vector! thank you

Comment: There's also a random phase, especially important for complex evecs - see https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/27477/matlab-mathematica-lapack-returning-3-different-eigenvectors